# How to setup readiness and liveliness probe values suitable for my application? Want to avoid writing code for http probe

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

I have an application that establishes SSE stream connections before starting and takes around 15 mins. to start. Then it is live and prints logs for 2-3 mins and then sits idle for around 5 mins. This log pattern repeats.

Problem: the pod is being restarted due to tcp socket connection issue. I tried to provide increased values in the configurations which helped resolved the frequent restart of the pod down to 2 times in 24 hrs but I don't want it to restart as my application is up and running. Why is it restarting? Why it is finding that pod is unstable?

```
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 2000
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 2000
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 2000
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 2000
```

`kubectl describe pod` -

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  24m (x170 over 4d1h)  kubelet  Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 192.168.7.68:8080: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  22m (x170 over 4d1h)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: dial tcp 192.168.7.68:8081: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  21m (x170 over 4d1h)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: dial tcp 192.168.7.68:8080: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  5m54s (x175 over 4d)  kubelet  Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 192.168.7.68:8081: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: According to the configuration you've specified - it looks like your pod is failing for 30*2000 seconds, which are ~16 hours. 
Does the readiness probe pass? Or do the pods stay unhealthy? Are you certain the probe is successful? Can the client successfully connect to the pods and receive events?

Comment: Also for slowly starting pods consider using [startup probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes)

Comment: Yes I'm fairly certain that clients were able to connect to the pods.

Comment: Try to `kubectl describe pod` to see if there are any failed probes events.

Comment: @moonkotte updated your request

Comment: @bosari Well, you see that probes are failing. You should tune them to start passing and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: @moonkotte I understand that but by tune in what you mean? I already mentioned the frequency and other details of my application. What values will be best suited is my question.

Comment: @bosari It's not about frequency, it fails all the time and @Yaron correctly said restart happens after 30*2000 seconds = all failed probes. You need to fix why tcp probe fails. it can be incorrect port, application doesn't listen to the specified port. Try troubleshoot your application first, e.g. with telnet if can actually open a TCP socket on 8080 (most like no, since there are failed checks). Or change probe to `HTTP request` or [liveness command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I'm working on moving to liveliness commands. something like cat healthy